# How to return all even values to the beginning of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to organize the arrays that are inside an array so that the first numbers in the array are even

For now I can only scroll through the arrays, I couldn't implement the logic

```
let matriz = [
    [5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 9],
    [2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
]

for (let i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    let innerArrLength = matriz[i].length
    for (let j = 0; j < innerArrLength; j++) {
        if (matriz[i][j] % 2 === 0) {
            // code
        } else {
            // code
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 3):

You could sort the array by taking a function which returns `true` fro even values.

```js
const
    move = (array, fn) => array.sort((a, b) => fn(b) - fn(a)),
    array = [5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 9];

move(array, v => v % 2 === 0);

console.log(...array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a less performant solution, `filter` can be very clear here:

```js
let matriz = [
    [5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 9],
    [2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
]

for (let i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
  matriz[i] = matriz[i].filter(x => x%2 == 0)
                        .concat(
                         matriz[i].filter(x => x%2 != 0))
}

console.log(matriz)
```

(the problem is that you traverse twice every inner array and you could do it with a single pass)